# Android File Transfer not working for transferring music files

Tags: file-transfer, music, macos

I have a Mac, and I want to delete all the music on my phone and replace it with all the music on iTunes in my Mac. I've done this before, but it is not working.

For some reason, my music is not in the music folder.

[image]

This is odd because I do have lots of music on my Android device. Here is my Android File Manager on my actual LG G3 on Android 6.0:

[image]

So I do have music, but it doesn't show in Android File Transfer. Also, when I try dragging my music from Finder into the empty music folder in Android File Transfer, only one song transfers, and it doesn't actually show on my LG G3.

How can I fix this issue and properly transfer music from iTunes on my Mac to my Android LG G3?

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest checking if there are any updates available, both for your MAC and Android File Transfer.

Next, something you can try is clearing the cached data for the storage on your device.

This has worked in the past for other users who have had similar issues with empty folders in the past. It's a fairly short and simple procedure that can't hurt to try. You can do that with the following steps:

1. Go to phone Settings
2. Select Application Manager
3. Tap on the 3 dots
4. Select 'Show System Apps'
5. Search for 'External Storage and Media Storage'
6. Clear Cache and Data
7. Reboot the phone

This will rebuild the database without deleting any of your data. It may take a while for everything the be initialized again.

Let me know if this helps!

Source(s):
http://androidforums.com/threads/android-file-transfer-on-mac-showing-empty-folders-on-phone.638113/ *Last post*

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/UqQZmSd7hAg *Best answer*